# Google Cloud Endpoints: Authorise only my android application

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm quite new to app engine and I'm trying to ensure that only my android application and web app hosted at [my-project].appspot.com are the only two apps that can access the endpoints.

I've tried to follow the [Google documentation here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth) but it's pretty vague I think (or I'm just too much of a noob).

I've added the client id's generated using the debug.keystore and my production keystore, and the web client id generated for [my-project].appspot.com, to the clientIds paramater of the @Api annotation:

```
@Api(
    name = "myEndPoint",
    version = "1.0",
    clientIds = {Ids.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Ids.ANDROID_DEBUG_CLIENT_ID, Ids.ANDROID_RELEASE_CLIENT_ID},
    audiences = {Ids.ANDROID_AUDIENCE},
    namespace = @ApiNamespace(
            ownerDomain = "my.domain.com",
            ownerName = "my.domain.com",
            packagePath = ""))

public class MyEndPoint {
...
}
```

The documentation says for android apps you also have to generate a web client id and use it as the audience. I wasn't sure what URL to use when creating it so currently the `Ids.ANDROID_AUDIENCE` is exactly the same as the webclient id I generated for the appspot.com app.

When I tried to test this by compiling the app with a newly generated debug.keystore (one that there was no client ID for) I was still able to use the endpoint.. I belive it should have blocked access to the endpoint at this stage?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't need the user to log in to use the endpoint, I just want to make sure that only the app itself is allowed to make requests.

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly the same thing. Did you find a suitable solution?

Comment: Also trying to do the same thing. Based on all my research, it seems that it is not possible.